# Reducing cyclomatic complexity in c++

Tags: c++

I want to ask that for a simple if else statement with multiple conditions how
can the cyclomatic complexity be reduced ?
For istance:

```
   std::string x; 
   if(cond)
     x = "Value1";
   else if(cond2)
   {
    if(cond3)
       x = "Value2";
    else if(cond4)
       x = "Value3";
    else
       x = "Value4";  
   }
   else if(cond5)
     x = "Value6";
   else if(cond6)
     x = "Value7";
```

Comment: you draw a table with all possible `true`/`false` combinations of all conditions and the value `x` has in each case and then you look for patterns

Comment: Its already fine @Nagy

Comment: _x += !!cond+!cond*(2*!!cond3+3*!!cond4+4*!cond3*!cond4)+!cond*!cond2*!!cond5*5+!cond*!cond2*!cond5*6_ 
No branches -- You're welcome.  :)

Comment: thank you Chris but I dont whink this will work for me :)

Comment: _"I dont whink this will work for me"_ In that case your question is unclear. Why doesn't it work for you?

Comment: @ThomasSablik Do you _really_ think Chris's example is a sensible solution? Or was meant as such?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Yes, I think after formatting this and splitting it into variables to make it readable it is a possible way to reduce the cyclomatic complexity

Comment: @ThomasSablik You mean, like turning it back into the OP's original code? I really don't see the purpose of your comments...

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings No, I mean like turning it into lines: `x += !!cond;` instead of `if (cond) x += 1;`. You can encapsulate more complex conditions into functions without if-else cascades and use it in mathematical formulas.

Comment: @ThomasSablik You're taking a joke too far.

Comment: That's not a joke for me. That's production code I've seen in large logistic companies. Instead of using if-else cascades the temporary results were stored in temporary variables and branches that shouldn't be added were set to 0.

Comment: I've also seen this technique in production code, for bottleneck areas of the code that need to be highly performant.  (Not as a generally used technique everywhere in the codebase.)

Comment: @ChrisUzdavinis gotta say, I was not expecting that when I clicked on "Show more comments"

Comment: @NagyKlara I think you would receive a lot more useful answers if you could share what those `cond` actually are. I mean, if they are just all `bool` you can't really simplify it but if they are "complex" statements there could be a simpler representation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the bits in an unsigned int to declare properties, and combine those properties to define masks. A `dispatch` function uses the `x` value and a `flag` value to test the bits and respond accordingly.

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

// Properties
static constexpr const auto C1 = 1u << 0;
static constexpr const auto C2 = 1u << 1;
static constexpr const auto C3 = 1u << 2;
static constexpr const auto C4 = 1u << 3;
static constexpr const auto C5 = 1u << 4;
static constexpr const auto C6 = 1u << 5;

// Masks (combination of properties)
static constexpr const auto C2C3 = C2 | C3;
static constexpr const auto C2C4 = C2 | C4;

// Dispatch operation based on flag (will jump, not branch)
int dispatch(int x, std::uint32_t flags) {
  switch (flags) {
    case C1:
      return x + 1;
    case C2:
      return x + 4;
    case C2C3:
      return x + 2;
    case C2C4:
      return x + 3;
    case C5:
      return x + 5;
    case C6:
      return x + 6;
    // add more cases as needed...

    default:
      // anything not specified is considered an error
      throw std::runtime_error("invalid flags");
  }
}

#define ASSERT(pred)                       \
  do {                                     \
    if (!(pred)) {                         \
      std::cerr << "expected " #pred "\n"; \
    } else {                               \
      std::cout << "ok " #pred "\n";       \
    }                                      \
  } while (false)

#define EXPECT_THROW(pred)                                \
  do {                                                    \
    bool thrown = false;                                  \
    try {                                                 \
      std::cout << (pred) << "\n";                        \
    } catch (...) {                                       \
      thrown = true;                                      \
    }                                                     \
    if (thrown) {                                         \
      std::cout << "ok " #pred "\n";                      \
    } else {                                              \
      std::cerr << "exception not thrown in " #pred "\n"; \
    }                                                     \
  } while (false)

int main() {
  // Only these should succeed
  ASSERT(dispatch(0, C1) == 1);
  ASSERT(dispatch(0, C2) == 4);
  ASSERT(dispatch(0, C2C3) == 2);
  ASSERT(dispatch(0, C2C4) == 3);
  ASSERT(dispatch(0, C5) == 5);
  ASSERT(dispatch(0, C6) == 6);

  // Anything else should be a failure (there are 2^6 = 64 combinations and only
  // 6 should succeed)... only a few are presented
  EXPECT_THROW(dispatch(0, C1 | C2));
  EXPECT_THROW(dispatch(0, C1 | C3));
  EXPECT_THROW(dispatch(0, C3 | C4));
  EXPECT_THROW(dispatch(0, C3));
}
```

Sample run:

```
$ clang++ example.cpp -std=c++2a -Wall -Wextra
$ ./a.out 
ok dispatch(0, C1) == 1
ok dispatch(0, C2) == 4
ok dispatch(0, C2C3) == 2
ok dispatch(0, C2C4) == 3
ok dispatch(0, C5) == 5
ok dispatch(0, C6) == 6
ok dispatch(0, C1 | C2)
ok dispatch(0, C1 | C3)
ok dispatch(0, C3 | C4)
ok dispatch(0, C3)
```

The dispatch function can be easily modified to add more cases. It would be more beneficial if the properties/flags had a more meaningful name.

Answer (score 2):

I had to google it. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) says:

> Cyclomatic complexity is a software metric used to indicate the complexity of a program. It is a quantitative measure of the number of linearly independent paths through a program's source code.

You can draw a table or graph:

```
                            *
                            |
                   ----------------------
                  |      |      |       |
                cond   cond2  cond5   cond6
                  |      |      |       |
                x+=1     |    x+=5    x+=6
                         |
                 -----------------
                 |       |       |
               cond3   cond4   else
                 |       |       |
               x+=2    x+=3    x+=4
```

Now you can see that no two branches lead to the same result. If we could find branches that lead to the same result then we could try to reduce the number of paths. Also without more information I have to assume that all conditions are independent. If there are relations between them, for example `cond2 => cond3` then you could reduce the number of branches.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){ 
    bool cond,cond1,cond2,cond3,cond4,cond5,cond6;
    
    cond6=true;
    int x=10;
    x+=cond?1:(cond2?(cond3?2:(cond4?3:4)):(cond5?5:(cond6?6:0)));
    
    printf("%d",x);
}
```

Comment: That doesn't change the cyclomatic complexity.

Comment: @Nagy you only asked for it. It is complex and time consuming . I would prefer `cyclomatic approach`.

Comment: @Thomas exactly OP approach is the best one.

Answer (score -1):

Say this whole block of code that is complex is in FunctionMain(), you could move this code into another function and just call that function. That way the complexity is moved to lower level function and main code readable.

Another way is you split the segments in this code into functions which are readable.

Comment: this block of code is in a loop and the loop is part of a method that is used by another method.

Comment: won't the cyclomatic complexity remain the same if i just split the method in multiple methods but the logic remains the same ?

Comment: The "cyclomatic complexity" is already fine, so you just need to consider readability, which is also fine, unless the conditions are complex or the function they're in is large... in which case you just need to introduce some more variables and functions.

Comment: yes this statement's function overall complexity it's large and I would like the reduce it by reduceing this statement's complexity.

Comment: this reminds me of how I cleaned my room as a kid. Putting it inside a function does not reduce complexity, just like dropping everything under your bed doesn't make an organized room

Comment: @NagyKlara These complex conditions comes up and it's not like you can get away with it but the least you can do is make it more readable. So hiding this under a function would make the code readable in what the these conditions are doing. I think what you want is improve the readability here so someone else understands what's happening.